# Intext citation is showing full title in overleaf

Tags: natbib

I m using Harvard referencing style with `natbib` in Overleaf for my dissertation.

I'm using the following entry

```
@MISC{regulusattack,
title = {TESLA MODEL 3 SPOOFED OFF THE HIGHWAY – REGULUS NAVIGATION SYSTEM HACK CAUSES CAR TO TURN ON ITS OWN},
month = Aug,
year = {2019},
howpublished={https://www.regulus.com/blog/tesla-model-3-spoofed-off-the-highway-regulus-navigation-system-hack-causes-car-to-turn-on-its-own/}
}
```

and it's generating the following in-text citation:

> " (TESLA MODEL 3 SPOOFED OFF THE HIGHWAY – REGULUS NAVIGATION SYSTEM
> HACK CAUSES CAR TO TURN ON ITSOWN2019)"

which is not acceptable.

This is the case with one other website, while all other websites, articles and proceedings citations are OK.

Comment: The entry has no author, something else has to be shown instead of the author. Here the style apparently chose the title. What would you like to see instead? Please also tell us more about your document setup (there are several broadly Harvard styles available for `natbib`), ideally in the form of a short example document that reproduces the output you are asking about with as little code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: The problem is solved, I was not using the author field, and when I did, I used it empty. Later on, I tried to add something in the author field and it works. Thanks for your help with adding the author.